# How to go about embedding Google Visual API chart into a JasperReports?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jasper-reports, google-visualization

I have a complicated Google Visual API chart that I need to add to a JasperReport. I know that JasperReports has its own charts, but I have to create a new chart for this. Is there anyway I can emded this Google API visual chart into JasperReports?

Comment: Can you convert your chart to an image and then added it to the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used google Image API instead of Visual API and embedded the images in the Report. Jasper's own charting feature has limited functionality and it didn't work out for my requirement.